# Need save button to save and then redirect

Tags: redirect, button

I need to add a redirect to the button, so when users click the save button for the update profile page it redirects them to the updated profile

```
     <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true"/>
     <button class="btn form-submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Publish Ad" type="submit"><?php _e('Save', 'agrg') ?></button>
```

Please Help

Comment: Set the correct `action` attribute on your `form` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this on **server side**.

You can do this using PHP like that :

`<?php header('Location: http://www.your-website.com/your/path'); ?>`

and the user will be redirected to `/your/path`.

[Documentation available here](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php).